# Calculate number of observations created over period using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For each observation in my data, I'm trying to come up with the number of observations created in the previous 7 days.

```
obs       date
 A      1/1/2000
 B      1/4/2000
 C      1/5/2000
 D      1/10/2000
```

Would become:

```
obs       date       births last week
 A      1/1/2000            0
 B      1/4/2000            1
 C      1/5/2000            2
 D      1/10/2000           2
 E      1/20/2000           0
```

Is it possible to get this using the rolling_count method?

Edit 1: The approach below by Karl works well but is a bit slow. Any ideas on how to implement this more quickly short of cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like the following (although depending on the structure of the data I think you could do it more elegantly and efficiently ... I imagine this is slow):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

          date
obs           
A   2000-01-01
B   2000-01-04
C   2000-01-05
D   2000-01-10
E   2000-01-20

def past7(x,df):
    back = x['date'] - dt.timedelta(days=7)
    return df[(df['date'] >= back) & (df['date'] < x['date'])].count()

df['births_last_7days'] = df.apply(lambda x: past7(x,df),axis=1)
print df

         date  births_last_7days
obs                              
A   2000-01-01                  0
B   2000-01-04                  1
C   2000-01-05                  2
D   2000-01-10                  2
E   2000-01-20                  0
```

Comment: Worked, but I had to change the code to `return df[(df['date'] >= back) & (df['date'] < x['date'])].count()[0]`

Comment: That makes sense. I made `obs` the index so `count()` is returning a scalar in mine.